# Firefox 56.0 (64-bit) crashing Tabs after upgrade

Tags: upgrade, firefox, crash

I've upgraded Xubuntu 16.04.3 last night amongst with Firefox and Firefox is crashing all the times.
I get a message:

> Gah. Your tab just crashed. We can help you!
>
> Choose Restore This Tab to reload page content. Will you help us?
>
> Crash reports help us diagnose problems and make Firefox better.
>   Report this tab.

I've opened Firefox in terminal and this is showed:

```
###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error:
(msgtype=0x24003F,name=PContent::Msg_LoadProcessScript) Closed channel:
cannot send/recv

[Parent 1989] WARNING: pipe error (57): Connection reset by peer: file
/build/firefox-l1g98U/firefox-56.0+build6/ipc/chromium/src/chrome/
common/ipc_channel_posix.cc,
line 353

###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error:
(msgtype=0x420017,name=PHttpChannel::Msg_DeleteSelf) Channel error:
cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error:
(msgtype=0x420017,name=PHttpChannel::Msg_DeleteSelf) Channel error:
cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error:
(msgtype=0x420017,name=PHttpChannel::Msg_DeleteSelf) Channel error:
cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error:
(msgtype=0x420017,name=PHttpChannel::Msg_DeleteSelf) Channel error:
cannot send/recv


###!!! [Parent][MessageChannel] Error:
(msgtype=0x150078,name=PBrowser::Msg_Destroy) Channel error: cannot
send/recv
```

---

any suggestions to solve the problem please?

Comment: I am seeing this a lot as well on Lubuntu.

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved.

Had to go: 
in Location enter:
   **about:config**

Type in filter box:
   **browser.tabs.remote**

Set both settings to false:
   **browser.tabs.remote.autostart = false
   browser.tabs.remote.autostart.2 = false**

Restart Firefox.

No crashing after that.

Comment: You're the best Bro!!! Thank you!